How to use docker cache bind mount with non-root user
I am trying to figure out how to take advantage of buildkit cache mounts for a python image that doesn't run as root.
Building as root…
FROM python:3.12.4
ENV XDG_CACHE_DIR=/root/.cache
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache \
    pip install django

The logs don't indicate any issues. Build when I try to cache as a user…
FROM python:3.12.4
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN adduser --home "$HOME" \
            --disabled-password \
            --disabled-login \
            user \
 && chown -R user:user "$HOME"
USER user
ENV PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" \
    XDG_CACHE_DIR="$HOME/.cache"
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache \
    pip install --user django

I see a warning in the logs:

WARNING: The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.

I have been unable to find a way to alter the permissions or ownership of these mount directories to make pip happy. Is it only possible to take advantage of this feature when the user doing the building is root?

You can set uid/gid for the cache directory (default is 0, i.e.root); see https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run---mounttypecache . Try RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/user/.cache,uid=user pip install
